# 3 points collide in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In Nakajima's book, "Lectures on Hilbert Schemes of Points on Surfaces", he gives an explicit description of the corresponding ideal for two points colliding in $\mathbb{C}^2$. This basically corresponds to the point itself plus the direction of the collision. I am trying to figure out an explicit ideal for when 3 points collide. Specifically I would like the generators of the ideal.

You should be able to think of three-point collision as two points colliding, then collide that "point" with the remaining point. But it shouldn't matter which two points you collide first, so I'm not sure what information I need. Maybe if I have three points collide at the origin, say, then I need the three vectors that those three points enter at?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. A triple point is a local Artin $k$-algebra of dimension $3$. There are only two up to isomorphism, which are $$k[t]/t^3,\textrm{ and }k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2).$$
In particular, every tripe point is planar.
Essentially, these rings reflect the only two ways in which you can get a triple point: the first, as a $2$-jet, namely by colliding three points on a smooth curve (say, one of the coordinate axes); the second, by letting collide to the origin two points on different axes.

Comment: This is good to know and actually jogged my memory about reading about this in "The Geometry of Schemes". However, knowing isomorphism classes isn't quite what I'm after. In the same way that knowing every double point is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ isn't the whole story. Realizing it as $\left< x^2, xy, y^2, \alpha x  - \beta y \right>$ as an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$  gives you the point $(0,0)$ and the direction that the two points collide $(\alpha, \beta)$. It is that description that I'm after.